# PostgreSQL GiST index - how to decide on whether to use buffering build or not?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, spatial, spatial-index

One of PostgreSQL GiST parameters is whether to use [buffering build](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/gist-implementation.html). However, I do not feel that the documentation is helpful enough for me to decide whether to use it or not. I have also found this presentation https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/0/07/Fast_GiST_index_build.pdf explaining buffering build in some detail but I cannot understand.

To make things more complicated, I have been constructing GiST indexes with default (buffering = auto) setting so I don't know if it is being used or not. I have a 15MB dataset which is a map (this is not so large, I understand effects are minimal. But still I am interested in its effects), so I suppose it is static data which can be bulk-loaded- but is the buffering build a bulk-loading technique? If I am not mistaken one of problems with GiST is bulk-loading?

Comment: I would say that you don't need to touch that setting & most likely you don't need to set it `on`. Setting it `off` might speed up **building** your index for *well-ordered data sets* though: that is, DML operations will be affected, not SELECTs. -- *By default, a GiST index build switches to the buffering method when the index size reaches effective_cache_size. It can be manually turned on or off by the buffering parameter to the CREATE INDEX command. The default behavior is good for most cases, but turning buffering off might speed up the build somewhat if the input data is ordered.*

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what well-ordered datasets are. Also, I don't understand your comments about SELECTs not affected. Isn't SELECT a DML too?

Comment: well ordered f.ex. when you have a `timestamp` column with `default current_timestamp` (your data will be inserted in a well-ordered manner in this case). You can probably see why this is not the *typical case* for GiST-like indexes. -- SELECT does not alter your data (unless it has some side-effect), thus it is not DML (data modifying language). INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs are typical DMLs.

Comment: Yeah, I am a bit confused about well-ordered datasets in the context of spatial data. Can I know if my spatial dataset/map is well ordered?

Comment: This ordering usually means the order given by the `<` and `>` operators (in the context of indexing). Some types have them, but *rather arbitrary and not usually useful in the real world* (f.ex. [ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)). Others don't support it at all. If your type does not support ordering, it can't be well-ordered either. -- I personally think this exception is only mentioned because of the [`btree_gist` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/btree-gist.html). Indexes listed there usually have a well-known, usable ordering.

Comment: Thanks! However while saying that the ordering is "rather arbitrary and not usually useful in the real world" still it makes a difference in buffering I am assuming so I am still a bit unsure.